# What kind of commands/scripts can I run when An EC2 instance launches?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I read from the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html):

> Also, because the script is not run interactively, you cannot include
>   commands that require user feedback (such as yum update without the -y
>   flag).

I have this commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
THIS_NODE_IP=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)
​
xvfb-run java -jar /home/ubuntu/selenium_server.jar -host $THIS_NODE_IP -role webdriver -port 8181 -maxSession 10 -maxInstances 10 -hub http://my-selenium-hub.com:8080/grid/register platform=LINUX &
```

...which do not seem to run. The selenium node that starts surely creates feedback in the console but I send it to background and it is not interactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your process is run as you launch the ec2 instance but it will stop when the user who launches the instance will disconnect

If you want to keep the process after user has disconnected, you can use `nohup` and if you want to get the output of the command you can use a redirection to a file like using `>`, something like

```
nohup <yourlongcommand> &> /path_to_file/nohup.grid.out&
```

you can then follow the execution of selenium from the `nohup.grid.out` file

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Frederic . According to the AWS docs , the user running the commands on startup is always root. Does he also disconnects?

Comment: yep most probably - in other provisioning case it works like this, user (root or other) connects to run the command then disconnect (anyway you have a timeout on user connection so it will timeout as nothing is done on this session)

Comment: I understand, but what about apache that runs as a service in the aws script example? Selenium is not run as a service obviously. That's why it is interrupted?

Comment: exactly - there's nothing under /etc/init.d/ for selenium. a few process (like apache) needs to be run even if no one is connected to the server so they run as service.

Comment: Understood.Thanks again!